# How to prevent WP overwriting my custom htaccess rewrites?

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I've used some custom rewrites implemented by the [Roots framework](https://github.com/retlehs/roots/).  Occasionally they get wiped: certainly if I visit Settings > Permalinks, but also at seemingly random times.

My htaccess reads so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/the-hit-centre/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/the-hit-centre/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/the-hit-centre/images/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^media/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried removing the

```
# BEGIN WordPress
```

comments, but then WP just writes a new block of code.

**Is there a hook I can call in functions.php that will prevent WP refreshing the permalinks?**

thanks, Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` after the end you should be able to add your own code. Anything between will get overwritten by WordPress

Comment: example code here http://www.whypad.com/posts/wordpress-prevent-wp-from-overwriting-custom-htaccess/258/

Comment: Thanks Drai - I'll follow whypad's lead and double up on the <IfModule, RewriteEngine On business..  The other approach I considered was to set .htaccess as not writable... Thanks!